# Multiple repositories in pom file doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, repository, pom.xml

as described here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html , i added two repos in my pom file

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>MavenCentral</id>
        <name>Maven repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>objectweb</id>
        <name>Objectweb repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.objectweb.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and then i tried to compile the project which hava a dummy dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then get:

```
 Failure to find org.test:dummy:jar:1.0.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MavenCentral has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

seems like it only query the first repo?

shouldn't it try connect to the second repo as well?

or do i totally misunderstand the purpose of "multiple repositories"?

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have the dummy dependency in your local, but cannot be found on either repo. This is a different error from 'not found in repo.' Maven was trying to resolve the dependency in your local cache by looking up the origin it came from.

Comment: you are right! i tried again with another dummy dependency and get these warnings saying can't be found in both repos. and the error message is "Could not find artifact org.test:dummy12:jar:1.0.0 in MavenCentral (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)"

Answer (score 0):

The artifacts you have mentioned are not existing in Maven Central which means maven can't find them. Apart from that why are you trying to configure Maven central a second time, cause Maven Central is defined in Maven by default so repository entries in your pom are useless.